# Install ruby using rbenv's downloaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I need to install `ruby 2.0.0-p645` and I use `rbenv`. I tried downloading it by running

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p645
```

But the internet in my college keeps dropping every few minutes, so the transfer was always closing with some 11MB remaining.

To counter that, I saw the url from where `rbenv` was downloading, and used `wget` to download the source file that `rbenv` was downloading. (using `wget -c` for resuming every time the connection closed).

Now I have the file, is there a way to install that ruby version now?

The file's [link on cloudfront](http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/5e9f8effffe97cba5ef0015feec6e1e5f3bacf6ace78cd1cdf72708cd71cf4ab) that I have on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Put the downloaded file into `~/.rbenv/cache`. You might need to create the directory first. Then run your `rbenv install` command again. Here is the link to the documentation for this: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#package-download-caching

---

To summarize, for future reference:

1. Download the file using `wget`
2. Create a `cache` folder in `~/.rbenv/` if it doesn't exist already.
3. Rename the downloaded file to `ruby-x.y.z-pabc.tar.gz`. Extract it and move it to `~/.rbenv/cache/`
4. Run `rbenv install x.y.z-pabc`

Comment: So I put the downloaded file into `~/.rbenv/cache/very_long_file_name`, then tried running `rbenv install` but it gave me Usage instructions, as if I am not using the command properly. I also tried setting the `RUBY_BUILD_CACHE_PATH` to `/Users/username/.rbenv/cache`. It's still not working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Edit: I realized that `rbenv install` was downloading a `tar.gz` file, so I renamed the downloaded file to `ruby-2.0.0-p645.tar.gz` and then "uncompressed" it (Just clicked on it, I am using OS X). Now I have a folder in `~/.rbenv/cache` with the name `ruby-2.0.0-p645`. The contents of the folder seem fine as well, since I opened a few files like `debug.c` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean `rvm install` with no arguments, but the same as you have above: `rvm install 2.0.0-p645`. Also you should leave the file with its original filename.

Comment: Thanks, you mean `rbenv install 2.0.0-p645`. And that did the trick!

Comment: Re your edit to my answer: I'm pretty sure you must put the *original* file into `cache`, without extracting/renaming. But you're the one who just did it. Are you sure that's right though??

Comment: Yeah. I had tried running `rbenv install 2.0.0-p645` before renaming, but `rbenv` was downloading from cloudfront again in that case. After I renamed it like I said, it worked fine. The issue was, the file I got after downloading from cloudfront had no extension, but I knew it's correct name was supposed to be  `ruby-2.0.0-p645.tar.gz` since rbenv showed it like [here](https://youtu.be/YAzAzU_Y6qo?t=4m30s).

Comment: Yes ending in `.tar.gz` sounds right. Weird it started out with no extension.

Comment: Good. Needn't extract that `.gz` file. Run `rbenv install -v x.y.z` would be good.

Comment: The naming in these examples was confusing to me. What is -pabc? 
Use wget to down the file to ~/.rbenv/cache as instructed. Then install the version you downloaded using the regular rbenv install commands, i.e., `rbenv install 2.7.6`. It works!

Comment: Ruby releases include a "patch" number like `p645` in the file `ruby-2.0.0-p645.tar.gz` above.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the following steps work.

```
1 Download the file using `wget/curl or any other way`
2. Create a `cache` folder in `~/.rbenv/` if it doesn't exist already.
3. Move the downloaded file to `~/.rbenv/cache/`
4. Run `rbenv install x.y.z` (ex. rbenv install 2.7.1`)
```

The difference from the above answer was,

```
- do not need to change file name 
- do not need to extract 
- if file rename to something random (ex. x.y.z-pabc) it show ruby-build: definition not found: x.y.z-pabc
```

Hope this can help someone.